# XSLT - How to append two lines to existing xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE configuration [
    <!ENTITY Reload_POST SYSTEM "Configuration_Reload_POST.xml">
]>
<configuration name="Ibis4Education">
    <jmsRealms>
        <jmsRealm realmName="jdbc" datasourceName="jdbc/${instance.name.lc}"/>
        <!-- jmsRealm realmName="qcf" queueConnectionFactoryName="jms/qcf"/ -->
    </jmsRealms>
    &Reload_POST;
</configuration>
```

I'd like to add another `<!ENTITY File_Name SYSTEM "file_location.xml">`  and another `&File_Name;` line..

I'm not that experienced with XSLT and can't find any good examples on Google, that's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 0):

The XSLT data model does not know any DTD nor any entity references so XSLT is not the right task for this unless you use a processor with an extension to output DTD details and entity references. I am only aware that the commercial editions of Saxon 9 support that, see https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/instructions/doctype.html and https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/instructions/entity-ref.html for two extension instructions supported in that processor. Even given those extension instructions I am not sure there is a way to process the existing DTD, unless you additionally add LexEv (http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/) by Andrew Welch to the tool chain.

So in general this is not a task you can solve with XSLT. Other XML tree manipulation ways however like DOM might also be limited when it comes to DTD manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

To make your XML input valid replace reserved XML character *&* with entity. It would be easier if you wrote expected output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE configuration [
<!ENTITY Reload_POST SYSTEM "Configuration_Reload_POST.xml"><!ENTITY File_Name SYSTEM "file_location.xml">]>]]></xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="configuration">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   <xsl:text>&amp;File_Name;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```